# android:shadowColor doesnt work for white color

Tags: android, shadow

There is simple xml-layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:shadowDy="10"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text="Button" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

When I set this as content view for activity, I see black shadow below text of my button. BUT if I change `android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"` to `android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"` - I see no shadow anymore. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself. For me it happened when the background was bright, and the blending of the white shadow on the bright background was not noticable. I changed the android:shadowRadius to be small (0.1) and that solved the problem.